# How to store files in directory that will be accessible to user in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have encountered a problem that the app needs to save pdf files downloaded from the internet in the downloads folder in both ios and android, but after searching for solutions on the internet I have not found anything that would help in this implementation. I would appreciate if someone could share their experience in implementing such functionality.

Comment: What did you end up doing ? I'm interested :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can add more details to your questions. It is preferred that you should attach some code or screenshots of your code so that you can get better help.

Comment: I apologise, I didn't quite get my message across correctly. I meant that I can't find any solution for saving files not in the application documents directory. I have not yet had any implementation of such functionality and don't know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

every app in android or ios has its own folder in the device storage,  android apps will be in the android directory.

you can use the path_provider plugin to get the directory of your app, all the information you need will be in this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

Comment: Yes, but if the user later needs to send the downloaded document to someone else, for example via telegram, they won't have that option, will they?

Comment: they can via file_picker plugin